# How to Create A REST webservice?

Tags: web-services, rest, jax-ws, jax-rs

Hi
I like to create a API webservice like Facebook, in Java? and how can i use PHP for access it???

Comment: You can start from here: http://robertdevenyi.com/blog/php-rest-server-put-delete-get-post.html

Answer (score 2):

There's an excellent book by O'Reilly - [RESTful Web Services](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529260).

Comment: is it telling about creating a RESTful Web Services?

Comment: There's a detailed description on the page mentioned above - don't forget to click on "full description".  I  found it an excellent resource for building a RESTful service.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/42873/1954 and http://wikis.sun.com/display/Jersey/Overview+of+JAX-RS+1.0+Features are two sites I started from that give a pretty nice overview of basic things you can do with REST. It is using Jersey in Java and you can google to find more examples of how to create specific services. The php side I can't really help you with though since I do not know php